# Memory realloc risk

Tags: c, memory-management

I need to know, are there any risks using the `realloc()` function to get additional memory?

For instance , I'm storing some stream into a `char*` variable. The problem is that we can't specify at the beginning the maximum size of the input stream, so we need from time to time to expand the memory area.

My question is: could reallocating memory cause data loss of my reallocated variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I lose data if I use it correctly?

No, there should never be any data loss when using `realloc`, it should be the syntactically the same as doing the below.

```
new_memory = malloc (new_size);

if (new_memory != NULL) {
    memcpy (new_memory, old_memory, old_size < new_size ? oldsize : new_size);
    free   (old_memory);
}

return newp;
```

#### What if reallocation fails?

If the reallocation failed (ie. no new memory could be allocated) the pointer to `old_memory` will still be valid, so please don't do like this:

```
my_memory = realloc (my_memory, new_size); 

  /*
   * if the allocation fails you will lose the pointer to your memory,
   * which will make you:
   *   a) lose your data
   *   b) have a memory leak
   * */
```

#### What does the standard say about `realloc`?

- [**pubs.opengroup.org - realloc**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/realloc.html)

Comment: Of course if your response to allocation failure is process abort then the naive code is fine

Answer (score 1):

You won't lose any data calling realloc but the allocation may fail, just like a malloc. That's usually regarded as terminal. If the memory block cannot be resized in-place a new block is created and the contents of the old block copied to the new block.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes, you could have a memory leak (and thus lose your data) if you do something like this:

```
void *data = malloc(5);
data = realloc(data, 999999999999999999999999999);
```

`data` would now be the `NULL`, since `realloc()` returns `NULL` if it fails. So to be safe, you could just have a separate pointer to test it:

```
void *data = malloc(5);
void *tmp = realloc(data, 999999999999999999999999999);
if (tmp != NULL) {
    data = tmp;
}
```

That being said, if `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` are failing to give you the memory you need, you've got a big problem no matter what. Either there's a bug in your program, you've got too much data to handle, or your box has too little RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember is that `realloc()` often won't just grow the block of memory in place; it will *move* your data. Old pointers to the memory become invalid. It's extremely important to keep track of any pointers to the original block and make sure they get updated; otherwise the data will *appear* to be lost or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Realloc will preserve your data as long as the specified size is larger than your data size.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/